# INSERT INTO Table (Column) VALUE (email)

Tags: c#, ms-access, insert-into, oledbcommand

I want to insert email in Table with only one column. I tried on 2 way. First time I tried with commandText and second time I tried with parapeters. But the both solution give me the same error.

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.'

I don't see any error in INSERT STATEMENT. Maybe the problem is in TABLE?

```
 using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
 {
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT (email) FROM [User] WHERE [email] LIKE '" + userEmail + "';";
    conn.Open();
    int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); // This passed
    if (count == 0)
    {
        string query = @"INSERT INTO User (email) VALUES (@email)";
        string cmdText= @"INSERT INTO User (email) VALUES ('"+userEmail+"')";
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, conn);
   //     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", "userEmail");
       // command.CommandText = query;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // I GOT ERROR HERE
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: that's no problem

Comment: well I need to insert users in Table.

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) alert!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`User` is a keyword. You should `INSERT INTO [USER]` instead

Comment: as mentioned here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/286335/list-of-reserved-words-in-access-2002-and-in-later-versions-of-access

Comment: yeah that's it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
string cmdText= @"INSERT INTO User (email)) VALUES ('"+userEmail+"')";
```

you have one ')' too many after (email)

Comment: that's no problem I didn't have two ) in second string but I got error again.